# TbNavbar containing TbBadge updates with ajax in yii

Tags: ajax, yii

I am looking to clear the label in tbbadge onclick and update a field in db. The badge is in my tbnavbar.

Can i even update it like this? I have also thought of using a widget and get it from view. Would that be better?

Currently I have:

```
<?php 
$count =Like::model()->product();
$badge=$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbBadge', array(
        'type'=>'info',
        'label'=>$count,
        'htmlOptions'=>array(
                'onclick'=>''; // this is where i don't know what to do.     
;?>

<? $this->widget(
    'bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar',
//stuff,
 '<li class="dropdown pull-right">
         <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" >Notice'. $badge . '<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu"> Item </div></li>',
```

I've tried:

```
$.ajax( {
         url:like/listStatChange,
         success:function() {
            $(#badge).val();
      });
```

Other things I've tried... adding `<div id="badge">'. $badge .` and did `'onclick'=> '$( "#badge" ).remove();'`. That of course won't post to db, but I wanted to see if it at least clears. It didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. this work with TbgridView but i dont know work this for navbar

At the first you must add id attribute to yor tbnavbar.
then
add ajaxlink, where

'success'=>'js:function(data){$.fn.yiiGridView.update("YOUR_NAVBAR_ID",{});}'

Comment: thanks. I tried it; it did run something. i'm going to try it again but i thought yiigridview.update applies to only cgridview?